# apache + mod_wsgi restart keeping active tasks

Tags: django, apache, task, wsgi

Im running my django project using apache + mod_wsgi in daemon mode. When I have to make the server notice changes in the source code, I touch the wsgi.py file, but I have an issue with this approach.

Some tasks that are triggered from the front-end take 10 minutes to complete. If I touch the wsgi file while one of this long tasks are running, they get killed by the restart.

Is there any way to make the server to refresh the code, but keeping the previous unfinished tasks running until the are done?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't run long-running tasks in web processes. Use an offline task manager like Celery.

Comment: I have Celery + Rabbitmq configured and running some cron jobs, but I never used it for anything else! If I receive a request for a long-running task, invoking a long-running function like function.delay() will avoid the task to stop when I reset the server?

Comment: As long as by "server" you mean the Apache/WSGI process, then yes.